# Dividing a number in loop until it satisfies a condition = 0

Tags: c++, divide

I have to input a value in the program and keep dividing it by 4 until it reaches the number 0.  But when I run it, it doesn't stop at 0, it keeps repeating 0 forever.  What is wrong with the code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double input;
    cout << "Enter an Integer: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << input << "/ 4 ";
    do
    {
        input = input / 4;
        if (input >= 0)
            cout <<" = "<< input << endl;
        cout <<input << " /4";
    }
    while ((input >= 0) || (input != 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: There are a few impressive misunderstandings in that sample. `double input;
cout << "Enter an Integer: ";`

Comment: We will not ignore your mistakes. Instead, we will help you correct them. The onus is still on you to follow site rules, although we understand that you may still require guidance. Please start by fixing your indentation.

Comment: `while ((input >= 0) || (input != 0));` is the one you should try and understand.  Where does this condition fail, and when is it true.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe. Classic. Haha.

Comment: It will never be ZERO. Because ZERO multiply by any number is ZERO.

Comment: Where are you dividing by 4?

Comment: you never manipulate the value in the loop, so as long as you enter a value that satisfies the condition it  won't break the loop unless you tell it to or enter a new value that doesn't satisfy the condition in the loop

Comment: printing the value of input then printing the text "/4" isn't dividing anything, it's just a visual.

Comment: Dividing a `double` by `4` does not necessary lead to a number whose value is `0`. See http://ideone.com/fHOV7M. Hope that helps you figure out how to refine your code.

Comment: `while ((input >= 0) || (input != 0));` will loop forever. If `input` is 0, then `input >= 0` is true. If `input` is not 0, then `input != 0` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my three cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const long long int DIVISOR = 4;

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an Integer (0 - Exit): ";

        long long int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        do
        {
            std::cout << n << " / " << DIVISOR;
            n /= DIVISOR;
            std::cout << " = " << n << std::endl;

        } while ( n );

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter an Integer (0 - Exit): 1000

1000 / 4 = 250
250 / 4 = 62
62 / 4 = 15
15 / 4 = 3
3 / 4 = 0

Enter an Integer (0 - Exit): 0
```